# Server-Side Javascript set charset on HTTP.Get

Tags: serverside-javascript

how to set charset in Server-Side Javascript (HTTP.Get)? Because I use HTTP.Get, and garbled return, any body can help?

please find my script below

```js
var url = 'https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken';
var contentType = 'application/json';
var payload = '{"clientId":"zcb2e6uqb9jqylp8qq8aw6ju","clientSecret":"nYfUJpCoZb3LO3XQAEAw4tGv"}';
  
var imgURL = 'https://www.cathaypacific.com/content/dam/focal-point/digital-library/global-marketing/gatwick/Gatwick_airport_convenience.jpg/_jcr_content/renditions/cq5dam.rendition.900.600.jpg';
try {
  var reqHeaderNames = ["Content-Type", "charset"];
  var reqHeaderValues = ["text/html", "utf-8"];
  var response = HTTP.Get(imgURL,reqHeaderNames,reqHeaderValues);
  Write(response.Status + '<br />'); 
  Write(response.Content + '<br />'); 
  
  
} catch (e) {

  Write("<br>e: " + Stringify(e));

}
```

[image]

Comment: somebody can help?

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with that, read the manual of Java and you will be able to do it. ^_%